# Can community user create Account in community page?

Tags: apex, trigger, community, create-records

I want to create account in community page when a community user clicks the button in VF page set in community page.

I tried many ways but now I am aware this is impossible by limitation of the Communities license.

But is there no other way?(like using Apex trigger or process builder or something else)
I could not even think of alternative way.
The owner of the account record does not have to be the community user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible as the community user get only read only access to the account which he belongs to. They don't get access to Create Account. or you can give your requirement, so can guide you different way.